# How to show that these two functions are $L^\infty$ multipliers?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose there are two multipliers,
$$m_1(\xi)=\frac{|\xi|^s}{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}}$$
and
$$m_2(\xi)=\frac{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}}{1+|\xi|^s}$$
where $s\in (0,\infty)$. My question is: are they $L^\infty$ multipliers? This question is trivial for $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$ (applying Mihlin multiplier theorem), but how about $L^\infty$?

Note: I try to divide them into low and high frequency parts, but I don't know how to deal with the high frequency part...

Comment: By duality this is the same as asking for boundedness in $L^1$ and this is equivalent to be the Fourier transform of a finite measure. Consider for example $m(\xi)=|\xi|^s/(1+|\xi|^s)$ which is similar to $m_1$. Then $m(\xi)=1-1/(1+|\xi|^s)$ and since $\hat \delta=1$ the answer is yes when $1/(1+|\xi|^s)$ is the Fourier transform of a $L^1$ function (or when the its Fourier transform is in $L^1$). This should be true for $s>0$ by similar arguments as for the other post, but I did not check the details.

Comment: It would be nice if you write down a complete proof...so that I can keep it!

Comment: I'm not sure about that, may be we can use the mean value theorem to estimate its order of decay. Such as $\frac{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}-|\xi|^s}{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}}=\int_0^1 \frac{(\theta+|\xi|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}-1}}{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}}\,d\theta\sim |\xi|^{-2}$ when $|\xi|\to\infty$, and, similarly, $\frac{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}-(1+|\xi|^s)}{(1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{s}{2}}\sim |\xi|^{2}$ when $|\xi|\to 0$. So, I guess if we take $n-1$ and $n+1$ order derivatives, we will obtain the the asymptotic behavior, ilke $|x|^{-n+1}$ near the origin and $|x|^{-n-1}$ for $|x|$ large...

Comment: But I don't know how to write it rigorously :(

Comment: $m_1$ behaves like $|\xi|^s$ near 0 and $1-m_1$ as $|\xi|^{-s}$ at infinity.